# How to flag something as "discuss with user X" in Trello?

Tags: trello

I often want to sit down with a team member and discuss a bunch of issues that I've qued up.

I've considered:

1. Create a dummy user "Discuss"  but then I don't know who I meant to discuss this with.
2. Comment to a user : @User Let's discuss.  But then we don't know what we've *already* discussed.  And there also isn't a way to find comments about "discuss with userX"  (you can only search on a single word). So, perhaps comment: discuss.
3. Create a separate card "Let's discuss XYZ" and then reference the *actual* card(s). A bit clumsy but it does the job.  Downside of that is that I then have to specify what part of that Card we should be discussing.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: You could use labels & apply them to the issues

Answer (score 1):

Use Menu | Filter Cards to search within a board. If you have an available Label, use that to mark cards to discuss.

Steps to take:

- Open the card you wish to flag and select "Labels" button on right
- Select "Change label names for board..."
- Pick an unused label and add your text, similar to "Discussion Required". Click Save
- Select the Label (make sure there is a checkmark)
- Add the members to the card who should be part of the discussion

Now you can use Filter by Label to find all cards needing discussion. (Menu | Filter Cards)

You can always add card Activity comments like:  @username @username2 Lets' discuss. Use another Activity comment to track what was discussed and when.

Tip:

Create a checklist of discussion topics

You can reference other cards by adding the other Card Number (#xxxx) to your activity comment.

Comment: Good idea, but all our labels are in use :(